# Prerequisition to add a wireless PCI card

Tags: wireless-networking, pci

Besides an extra unused PCI slot, are there any other requirements need to be met to install a wireless PCI card?

Comment: I'm sure the manufacturer of the card specify a few requirements that should be met.

Comment: Just so long as the card fits (PCI) and the drivers provided work for your OS you should be fine.